# Unclear about this use case on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on some feature using firebase and I need to send notification to the user on this scenario:

First-> User registers a value (not unique) let's say `ABCDEFG` which can also be registered by another user. So I save this in a table in `Firebase Realtime Db`.

Second -> I have another table which one of the fields is the field mentioned on the first step (so relation is many to many)

Third -> Once a new record is inserted, on my second step table, I want to send notification only to users which have this `ABCDEFG` field.

I don't really care who added the record, I just care that if that `ABCDEFG` is mentioned on the table, I want to send message to the user who has this one saved.

How can I achieve this in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Optional: I prefer not to make a login to user at all, is it doable in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Firebase Functions. Create a Trigger function that listens for data to be added to your database. In your case, `onCreate` would work - when a record is created in the database, your function would then run a query to find the matching records and send out your message (email via Sendgrid, push notification, whatever).

No login needed, though you may want to consider it so you get the correct details of whomever you're sending messages to.

Comment: No problem for correct details, the data will not be confidential. Can you please provide me an example? I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: Just a small question, how does firebase know which device has saved what?

Comment: It doesn't unless you tell it. So if this is a native app (for example), maybe you send over the FCM token for the device. Or maybe you have users register and provide their email address for email notifications. Etc. Firebase won't automatically send anything - you need to identify the users and devices (and store that info in Firebase) and then your cloud function can send what you want to whom you want.

Comment: which implies that I am unable to also write database rules without the user being authenticated

Comment: Yes and no. You can set up "anonymous" users (see that doc in Firebase) if you don't want them to actually create an account, and then you can use authenticated rules. Or you can lock down the database and use Firebase callable functions. Or...you have a number of options. I can't tell you exactly which one fits your use case, but there is a ton of flexibility if you look closely at all the options Firebase gives you to read/write/store data and run functions.

Comment: Thank you very much